# set order in radio group

Tags: android, radio-group

I got radio group, which contain 3 buttons:

- small
- medium
- big

and thats how it was putted to the layout. I don't know why but medium button interchanged with big button. I reverted it, so when I look at my layout now, everything is laying in properly order,but then I run my application and they are still in wrong order. Are there any parameters which sets the order in radio Group?

I got Relative Layout and this is the code which describe radio buttons

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/size"
    android:layout_width="186dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ingredients"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/small"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:text="Small" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/medium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:text="Medium" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/big"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:text="Big" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: no help without code..so plz post xml and java code

Comment: I dont know whats happens but after many runs everything is properly order